# 22003 8115 error with overflow bigint id

Tags: sql-server, django

My code runs fine in a single test. The `id` starts with 1 and increments by 1. However when I test the whole run in django, I've got this error.

For example, an `id` `601193234094856941` was inserted. In the whole run I have not more than 10000 inserts. This problem occurs in our development environment.

We have a work-around but we want to understand how it works and find a solution.

> ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. (8115) (SQLExecDirectW)')",

All variables are `bigint`. The id above has been correctly inserted in the database but apparently the id reached a value above the max of a `bigint` with later inserts.

Comment: Have a look at [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql). you'll notice that the maximum value of an int is `2,147,483,647`. That's a lot less that your value above. If you REALLY do have IDs going into the quadrillions, you'll need to use `BIGINT`. I'd also suggest you consider starting you seed at `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` (the lowest value a `BIGINT` can store). That gives you over 18 quintillion IDs to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided this seems to be what would be expected. the reference id 601193234094856941 exceeds the value for an INT type. The code below throws an error of "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.". Do you have additional information to provide that might help address your issue?

```
DECLARE @big       BIGINT = 601193234094856941
        , @regular INT;

SET @regular = @big;
```